# How should I create a custom form?

Tags: 7, forms

I create a module like this:

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu(){
    $items['mymodule/edit']=array(
        'title'=>t('Edit item'),
        'type'=>MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback'=>'mymodule_edit_view',
    );
    return $items;
}

function mymodule_edit_view(){
    //...
    $html.='<form '.$form_attr.'>';
    //...
    $html.='</form>';
    //...
    return $html;
}

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
    //...
}
```

I create a form in mymodule_edit_view, but when I access mymodelu/edit, the drupal did not call mymodule_form_alter. I do not want to create the form with drupal_get_form(), So how should I create the form?

Comment: You really, really should be using drupal_get_form(). Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: What is hook_form_alert()?

Comment: @AlexGill I should be mymodule_form_alter

Comment: Surely this shouldnt work anyway by not using form api or doesnt that matter?

Comment: For your reference and to get a clear idea about how drupal forms working check form_example module in http://drupal.org/project/examples . All possible format for forms is described in this module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't work as @Alex said, because you are not using Drupal's Form API. You should implement [`hook_form($node, &$form_state)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7), to create a form.

Sample code which creates a form with a single text field:

```
function MODULE_form() {
  $form = array();
  $form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Field description goes here...'),
    '#required' => TRUE, 
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: If I use the form api, how should I render the form by myself?

Comment: Basically, you need to recreate your form to one that goes through the Drupal form API. Then you can render the form into HTML using render(drupal_get_form('FORM_NAME'));

Comment: So where has the document to tell me how to set the field of $form, I mean what fields I could set and what value I could set

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/751826 and http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7 should be all you need.

Comment: @solomon_wzs Drupal's API is flexible enough, that you could do almost anything you can think of. Just refer to the [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module to see the example of form API, also see the link in the answer above for further information on Form API.